# Push уведомления приходят на разлогиненный телефон

Tags: java, push-уведомления, token, android-push-notification, authenticationtoken

Всем привет. Подскажите в каком направлении копать, куда смотреть.
Ситуация в следующем: если залогиниться под одним пользователем на мобильном телефоне (android, ios), отправить ему с сайта письмо, ему придет сообщение в приложениее в messages и также придет push уведомление на телефон. 
Если на этом телефоне сделать logout и залогинится на другом телефоне (не важно ios, android) под этим же аккаунтом пользователя. Если отправить сообщение с сайта, ему придет сообщение в приложении в messages на второй телефон и туда же придет и Push уведомление.

Если отправлять так некоторое количество раз, то push уведомление придет на первый телефон (на тот, на котором мы сделали logout).

Я проверял, когда пользователь логинится в приложении, для него в базе в таблице пользователей (есть поле deviceToken) куда генерируется токен для пользователя. Как только пользователь делает logout - токен удаляется.

При отправке сообщений с сайта я сомтрел логи томката на сервере (catalina.out): когда пуш приходит на верный телефон, я вижу в логах верный токен, но когда пуш приходит на тот телефон, где мы разлогинились, в логах вижу совершенно другой токен.
Может быть он где-то кешируется, не понимаю ?

Мой сервис для отправки push:

```
@Override
public void sendPushNotifications(EventEntity event, Collection<UserEventDto> users) {
    PushNotificationData data = buildPushNotificationData(event, users);
    Set<Long> usersToAddEvent = new HashSet<>();
    sendNotifications(data, usersToAddEvent);
    userDao.incrementUsers(new ArrayList<Long>(usersToAddEvent), event);
}
```

Далее идет сюда (тут тело формируется и т.д.):

```
private PushNotificationData buildPushNotificationData(Object entity, Collection<UserEventDto> users) {
        PushNotificationData data = new PushNotificationData();
        Date thresholdDate = new Date(UNREAD_NUMBER_TRACK_STARTED_TIMESTAMP);
        PayloadBuilder payload = null;
        Object dataAndroidString = null;
        Object notificationAndroidString = null;
        if (entity instanceof EventEntity) {
            EventEntity eventEntity = (EventEntity)entity;
            payload = buildApnsPayload(eventEntity);
            dataAndroidString = buildGCMData(eventEntity, eventEntity.getTitle());
//            notificationAndroidString = buildGCMNotification(eventEntity.getTitle());
        }
        if (entity instanceof MessageEntity) {
            MessageEntity messageEntity = (MessageEntity)entity;
            payload = buildApnsMessagePayload(messageEntity);
            dataAndroidString = buildGCMMessageData(messageEntity, messageEntity.getBody());
            notificationAndroidString = buildGCMNotification(messageEntity.getBody());
        }
        if (entity instanceof MyCheckListWebLinkEntity) {
            MyCheckListWebLinkEntity myCheckListWebLinkEntity = (MyCheckListWebLinkEntity)entity;
            payload = buildApnsReminderMessagePayload(myCheckListWebLinkEntity);
            dataAndroidString = buildGCMReminderMessageData(myCheckListWebLinkEntity);
            notificationAndroidString = buildGCMReminderMessageNotification(myCheckListWebLinkEntity);
        }
        data.setPayload(payload);
        data.setDataAndroidString(dataAndroidString);
        data.setNotificationAndroidString(notificationAndroidString);
        data.setThresholdDate(thresholdDate);
        data.setUsers(users);
        return data;
    }
```

Далее сюда (здесь и происходит отправка пуша):

```
public void sendNotifications(PushNotificationData data, Set<Long> usersToAddEvent) {
        Set<String> androidUsers = new HashSet<>();
        for (UserEventDto user : data.getUsers()) {
            try {
                int unreadNumber = 1;
                if (user.getClientAppVersion().after(data.getThresholdDate())) {
                    unreadNumber += user.getUnreadNumber();
                }
                String payloadString = data.getPayload().badge(unreadNumber).build();
                if (PlatformType.ANDROID.equals(user.getPlatform())) {
                    androidUsers.add(user.getDeviceToken());
                } else {
                    apnsServiceSingleton.push(user.getDeviceToken(), payloadString);
                }
                if (usersToAddEvent != null) {
                    usersToAddEvent.add(user.getId());
                }
            } catch (NetworkIOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception while sending apns message: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if (!androidUsers.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                androidPushService.push(new ArrayList<>(androidUsers), data.getDataAndroidString(), data.getNotificationAndroidString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception while sending GSM message: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Это конкретно для android:

```
    private ResponseDto execute(RequestAndroidDto requestDto) {
        PostMethod postMethod = null;
        String response = null;

        ResponseDto e;
        try {
            postMethod = new PostMethod("/gcm/send");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            postMethod.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "key=" + this.getKey());
            postMethod.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto), "application/json", "utf-8"));
            LOGGER.warn(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto));
            this.getClient().executeMethod(postMethod);
            response = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
            LOGGER.warn(response);
            e = (ResponseDto)this.objectMapper.readValue(response, ResponseDto.class);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var9) {
            LOGGER.warn("Exception while sending gcm push. " + response);
            throw new RuntimeException(var9);
        } catch (IOException var10) {
            LOGGER.warn("Exception while sending gcm push. " + response);
            throw new RuntimeException(var10);
        } finally {
            if(postMethod != null) {
                postMethod.releaseConnection();
            }

        }

        return e;
    }

    public final boolean push(List<String> to, Object data, Object notification) {
        if (to.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        RequestAndroidDto requestDto = new RequestAndroidDto();
        requestDto.registrationIds = to;
        requestDto.data = data;
//        requestDto.notification = notification;
        return this.execute(requestDto).success > 0L;
    }
```

Это для ios:

```
private synchronized ApnsService getApnsService() {
    if (apnsService == null) {
        this.apnsService = new ApnsServiceBuilder()
                .withCert(filename, certPassword != null ? certPassword : "123softteco321")
                .asPool(15).withCacheLength(1000).withSandboxDestination().withDelegate(new ApnsLoggerDelegate()).build();
    }
    return apnsService;
}

ApnsNotification push(final String deviceToken, final String payloadString) {
    return getApnsService().push(deviceToken, payloadString);
}

Map<String, Date> getInactiveDevices() {
    return getApnsService().getInactiveDevices();
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что на это влияет и как мне с этим бороться ? Буду очень благодарен за ответ или подсказку в каком направлении мне стоит посмотреть. Не судите строго, никогда не работал с подобным.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то смотреть нужно какие `users` приходят в `sendPushNotifications`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov можете пояснить что значит какие ?

Comment: Вы отправляете уведомления всем пользователям из коллекции `users`. Если уведомления приходят не туда, то либо `users` заполнен некорректными данными, либо методы `getDeviceToken()`/`getId()` возвращают некорректные значения